# Concatenating string outputs of a for loop in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, string-concatenation

I have a code which, after a nested for loop, provides me with a unique string in each iteration. I want to find a way to concatenate those outputs so that my final line is a single string of those unique strings. Ignoring how ugly and inefficient this code is, what steps can I take to achieve the desired result?

```
VOWELS = ('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U')

ad = "Desirable unfurnished flat in quiet residential area"
# remove all vowels, unless the word starts with a vowel

def is_vowel(c):
    return c in VOWELS

def mod3(ad):
    testAd =ad.split()
    for word in testAd:
        modAd = ""
        i = 0
        for char in word:
            if i == 0:
                modAd += char
            elif not is_vowel(char):
                modAd += char
            i+=1
        print(modAd)

mod3(ad)
```

my output for this code:
[image]

Otherwise, when I modify my code to look like this:

[image]

But my output is:
[image]

I don't believe a .join() would work here as it's not a list type. And I can't figure out where to put a string concat + anywhere without my for loop going bonkers. Any advice?

Comment: I think I might answered too early in my reply below. What is your expected result?

Comment: expected result should be a space between each modified word:
Dsrble unfrnshd flt in qt rsdntl ar

Comment: Check the updated answer, and if that is what you were looking for, please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a string `result` where you can concatenate your each iteration result and print that. You need to add spaces after each addition of words. So, append `+ " "` to your `result` variable as well.

```
def mod3(ad):
    result = ""
    testAd =ad.split()
    for word in testAd:
        modAd = ""
        i = 0
        for char in word:
            if i == 0:
                modAd += char
            elif not is_vowel(char):
                modAd += char
            i+=1
        result += modAd + " "
    print(result)
```

**Second option**: This is my take on it:

```
def mod4(ad):
    result = ""
    testAd =ad.split()
    for word in testAd:
          for i, char in enumerate(word):
              if i == 0:
                  result += char
              if i > 0 and char not in VOWELS:
                  result += char
          result += " "
    print(result)
```

Comment: There is no need to create a new variable. You can just store it once like your second option. You were just missing the + " " part.